# Sencha touch 2 cannot get Ajax calls working

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have this simple function which I call from my applications `launch()` function:

```
function ajaxCall(){
  Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'ajax/Hello!', // Request should go to host/ajax url as http get request
                 // and server should return plain text `Hello!` as answer
    success: function(response){
      prompt('Ajax call success!', response.responseText); // My own prompting method
    }
  });
}
```

The problem is that this request doesn't seem to get made. It doesn't show up on my Play framework server or in Google Chrome's network developer tab.

**EDIT**
Program also seems to get stuck to the `Ext.Ajax.request` function.

Comment: Try adding "Ext.Ajax" in the 'require' property in your app.js.

Comment: Are you calling ajaxCall() inside launch?

Comment: Yes I call that method from within my launch() method.

Comment: Is your sencha on the same domain of your server? sencha ajax cant run or cross-domain (you will need to use jsonp).

Comment: @Scoup All of my urls that I'm accessing are at the same server with the Sencha application files.

Comment: That is very strange. Your prompt is called? Can you check the requisition on chrome network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that I forgot to add the `Ext.Ajax` to my applications requires field. After adding it everything works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

The Following Code for ajax calling working well for me.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    async : true,
    url : 'api/login/',
    method : 'POST',
    jsonData : {
        "email":Ext.getCmp('loginUserNameTxtBoxId')._value,
        "pwd":Ext.getCmp('loginPasswordTxtBoxId')._value,
    },
    success : function (request, resp) {
        alert("in login success");
    },
    failure: function(request, resp) {
        alert("in failure");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your url should be a http url. You should also specify the action (GET, POST) for example. You already specified that you want to do an ajax call by using Ext.Ajax.request.

If you want to use parameters, use a parameter object.

example:

```
 Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : 'http://google.com/api/blabla',
        method: 'GET',
        params: {
            username: 'bla',
            password: 'blabla'
        },
        success: function(response, request) { console.log('success'); }
    });
```

Check the network tab in your chrome developer tools if the request has been made.

Comment: Sencha touch 2 Ext.Ajax documentation says that I don't have to add the complete url to make the call. It should work fine with '/ajax'. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: You are right. I just checked docs. if not specified the request uses the method GET. But on what do you execute the get method? host/ajax? What does your server return upon /ajax?

Comment: Server returns plain text ok answer for path `/ajax/something`. If I put in the browser `localhost:9000/ajax/Hello!` it returns plain text `Hello!` as an answer.

Comment: Also I can see from the chrome developer tab that my request never gets made as I specified in my question.